# Onclick of form element get the attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In general I have a `html`

```
<div id="test">
  <div class="group">
  <div class="qlist">
   <div id=q002>
    <div class="ilist">
    <div id="item070" class="i">
      <div>
           <input type="radio" id="ra11" name="ra">
           <label for="ra11">Option1.</label>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

What I am trying:

```
//open properties when click on item element
    $("#test.i > div > input[type='checkbox'], #test .i > div > input[type='radio']").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("xxx");
    });
```

How can I get the id `item070` when onclick on form element eg `radio`,`checkbox`..?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to find div with class `i`

```
$(document).on("click", "#ra11", function(){
   alert($(this).closest(".i").attr("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", "#ra11", function(){
   alert($(this).parent("div").parent("div").attr("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with jquery then look out here

[This link](http://jsbin.com/AmATehop/1/edit)

I just have included *parent()* to find id of parent

Also i refer to read this link  which will help you in next problem http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("#ra11").click(function(){
    var theId = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
});
```